# How to merge two different size DataFrames in Pandas to update one dataframe depends on matching partial values in one column with another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, merge

I am trying to code a task for work, so I made a simple case that simulates this task. I have two dataframes: `data_1` and `data_2`, and I would like to replace some rows in `data_1` with rows from `data_2` by condition of matching values in a column named `time`.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a = {
    'time':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'column_1':[2,2,2,2,2,2],
    'column_2':[3,3,3,3,3,3]   
}
b = {
    'time':[3,4,5],
    'column_1':[0,0,0],
    'column_2':[0,0,0]    
}
data_1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
data_2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
```

In the result, I would like to get dataframe like this:

```
time   column_1   column_2
0   1   2   3
1   2   2   3
2   3   0   0
3   4   0   0
4   5   0   0
5   6   2   3
```

I tried merge and replace methods in Pandas, but it was not successful. I did mask boolean array:

```
time_1 = list(data_1['time'])
time_2 = list(data_2['time'])
mask_array = np.zeros(len(time_1),dtype = bool)
for i, item in enumerate(time_1):
    if item in time_2:
        mask_array[i] = True
```

and I received:

```
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False])
```

But I could not replace `data_1` values with `data_2` values. What did I do wrong? It does not seem like a difficult task, but I could not find anything useful and just do not know what to do. I do not have a lot of experience with pandas, so maybe I do not understand something.

Comment: `data_2.set_index("time").combine_first(data_1.set_index("time")).reset_index()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) after setting index on `time` on both `data_1a` and `data_1b`, as follows:

```
data_1a = data_1.set_index('time')
data_1a.update(data_2.set_index('time'))
data_out = data_1a.reset_index()
```

[`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) modifies in place using non-NA values from another DataFrame. Aligns on indices.  Thus, when you set `time` as index on both `data_1a` and `data_1b`, [`.update()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) aligns on matching values in column `time` to perform the update of `data_1` by corresponding values of  `data_2`.

**Data Setup:**

```
a = {
    'time':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
    'column_1':[2,2,2,2,2,2],
    'column_2':[3,3,3,3,3,3]   
}
b = {
    'time':[3,4,5],
    'column_1':[0,0,0],
    'column_2':[0,0,0]    
}
data_1 = pd.DataFrame(a)
data_2 = pd.DataFrame(b)
```

**Result:**

```
print(data_out)

   time  column_1  column_2
0     1       2.0       3.0
1     2       2.0       3.0
2     3       0.0       0.0
3     4       0.0       0.0
4     5       0.0       0.0
5     6       2.0       3.0
```

Comment: Hello! Your decision helped me, thank you! I didn't know about update() method, interesting!

Comment: @gleb_shm  It's a relatively less commonly known function but handy when the usage condition met. Make good use of it.  Sometimes people may use the `combine_first()` method as mentioned in comment to achieve it.  But in that case you are reversing the subject and object by updating `data_2` with `data_1`.  Though could give same result but counterintuitive to reverse the subject and object and prone to error for some edge cases.